# SSL Identity Certificate to run an HTTPS Server on iOS

Tags: ios, networking, ssl, https

I'm trying to build an **HTTPS server in an iOS app**, in order to act as a proxy between my web-app and my external server.

I have managed to make an HTTP server by listening to a socket, either thanks to CFSocketRef or using the GCDAsyncSocket library.
I have also succeed to make a Mac app running an HTTPS server, using the GCDAsyncSocket library and thanks to my method "secureSocket:" below which secures the connection:

```
- (void)socket:(GCDAsyncSocket *)sock didAcceptNewSocket:(GCDAsyncSocket *)newSocket
{
    // (...)
    // secure the connection
    [self secureSocket:newSocket];
    // (...)
}

- (void)secureSocket:(GCDAsyncSocket *)sock
{
    // The root self-signed certificate I have created
    NSString *certificatePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"certificate" ofType:@"cer"];
    NSData *certData = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:certificatePath];
    CFDataRef certDataRef = (CFDataRef)certData;
    SecCertificateRef cert = SecCertificateCreateWithData(NULL, certDataRef);
    [certData release];

    // the "identity" certificate
    SecIdentityRef identityRef;
    SecIdentityCreateWithCertificate(NULL, cert, &identityRef);

    // the certificates array, containing the identity then the root certificate
    NSArray *certs = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:(id)identityRef, (id)cert, nil];

    // the SSL configuration
    NSMutableDictionary *settings = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithCapacity:3];
    [settings setObject:[NSNull null] forKey:(NSString *)kCFStreamSSLPeerName];
    [settings setObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES] forKey:(NSString *)kCFStreamSSLAllowsAnyRoot];
    [settings setObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES] forKey:(NSString *)kCFStreamSSLAllowsExpiredRoots];
    [settings setObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES] forKey:(NSString *)kCFStreamSSLAllowsExpiredCertificates];
    [settings setObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:NO] forKey:(NSString *)kCFStreamSSLValidatesCertificateChain];
    [settings setObject:(NSString *)kCFStreamSocketSecurityLevelNegotiatedSSL forKey:(NSString*)kCFStreamSSLLevel];
    [settings setObject:certs forKey:(NSString *)kCFStreamSSLCertificates];
    [settings setObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES] forKey:(NSString *)kCFStreamSSLIsServer];

    [sock startTLS:settings];
    [certs release];
}
```

The certificate I'm using is a self-signed server SSL certificate I have created with Keychain Access.
So I understand that I have to give the system a configuration set with an array containing an identity and a certificate. And it works fine on my Mac app.

The problem is to enable the SSL on the HTTP server of my iOS app.
The method "SecIdentityCreateWithCertificate()" which creates the identity doesn't exist on iOS and I don't know how to create an identity another way.

**How to create an SecIdentityRef on iOS (to enable SSL server side)? Did I miss something** like to store the public/private key in my app, or something else? Thank you so much.

Comment: It has been changed in CocoaAsyncSocket v7.4, some old option keys are now unavailable and will throw exception. Use GCDAsyncSocketManuallyEvaluateTrust and evaluate in -socket:didReceiveTrust: delegate instead. See my example in https://gist.github.com/hlung/6432966

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I will post a separate answer, as comments are not suitable for code sharing.
Here is what I use to import my PKCS12:

```
CFArrayRef keyref = NULL;
OSStatus sanityChesk = SecPKCS12Import((__bridge CFDataRef)p12Data, 
                                       (__bridge CFDictionaryRef)[NSDictionary 
                                                                  dictionaryWithObject:password 
                                                                  forKey:(__bridge id)kSecImportExportPassphrase], 
                                       &keyref);

if (sanityChesk != noErr) {
    NSLog(@"Error while importing pkcs12 [%d]", sanityChesk);
    return nil;
}

NSArray *keystore = (__bridge_transfer NSArray *)keyref;
```

The complete p12 content will be in the ***keystore*** array.

Comment: my code here uses the ARC, hence the need of the cryptic __bridge keywords ;)

Comment: I was doing the same. I get the same result with your code: _keystore_ array is empty.
If you have a better result with the same code, I guess it means that I don't generate or store my certificates right? What I did is to create a self-signed root certificate from Keychain Access then I store both .cer and .p12 files in my project bundle and I try to use them without success as you can see. Thank you for your time, I appreciate your help.

Comment: just to get it work ... why don't you try exporting some of yours working key/certificate pairs (e.g. development certs signed by Apple).

Comment: I have tried with a valid certificate and it worked. I have another issue but thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you need to import the identity using a PKCS #12 file. See listing 2-2 in https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Security/Conceptual/CertKeyTrustProgGuide/iPhone_Tasks/iPhone_Tasks.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001358-CH208-SW13 .

Comment: I have already tried that actually, but I can't make it working - it might be the right question here. I have imported my private key (p12 file) and used the extractIdentityAndTrust() function as shown by Apple in your link, but I always get an empty _items_ array that makes this function crashing while trying to access the first element of the array. Any idea about that?

Comment: If you have used the 'SecPKCS12Import' method it will return an NSArray containing NSDictionaries. The identity in the dictionary is stored under the key 'kSecImportItemIdentity', while the certificate chain (NSArray again) under the key 'kSecImportItemCertChain'. In meantime I am also looking for a way to create the identity in runtime, since I am not dealing with pre-loaded certs. Will post the result here if I find something ;)

Comment: Thanks @pmilosev. My problem is that I use the function _extractIdentityAndTrust_ as shown by Apple in the link above but the array _items_ I get is always empty:

`NSDictionary *optionsDictionary = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:@"myPrivateKeyPassword" forKey:(id)kSecImportExportPassphrase];
CFArrayRef items = CFArrayCreate(NULL, 0, 0, NULL);
    securityError = SecPKCS12Import(inPKCS12Data,
                                    optionsDictionary,
                                    &items);`