# SecPKCS12Import does not return any items

Tags: ios, ssl, ios6

I want to add certain CA certificates for TLS validation to the keychain of my iOS 6 application. The certificates are included in the Application Bundle. I do **not** want to add any *identity* (private key / certificate combination) which is described in several example.

The `SecPKCS12Import` call does not return any error, but unfortunately it does not return any certificate as well.

To let you reproduce my steps I took the Google Intermediate Certificate ('Google Internet Authority') as an example, and ran the following commands on the downloaded PEM certificate:

[image: COT].

```
#convert PEM certificate to PKCS12
openssl pkcs12 -export -in google.pem -nokeys -out google.p12 -passout "pass:google"
#verification
openssl pkcs12 -in google.p12 -passin "pass:google"
MAC verified OK
Bag Attributes: <No Attributes>
subject=/C=US/O=Google Inc/CN=Google Internet Authority
issuer=/C=US/O=Equifax/OU=Equifax Secure Certificate Authority
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
MIICsDCCAhmgAwIBAgIDFXfhMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBBQUAME4xCzAJBgNVBAYTAlVT
MRAwDgYDVQQKEwdFcXVpZmF4MS0wKwYDVQQLEyRFcXVpZmF4IFNlY3VyZSBDZXJ0
[...]
ARlIjNvrPq86fpVg0NOTawALkSqOUMl3MynBQO+spR7EHcRbADQ/JemfTEh2Ycfl
vZqhEFBfurZkX0eTANq98ZvVfpg=
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

Afterwards I bundled the file in my application where the following code got executed:

```
NSMutableDictionary * options = [[[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init] autorelease];
[options setObject:@"google" forKey:(id)kSecImportExportPassphrase];
CFArrayRef items = NULL;
NSData *certData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:[NSBundle pathForResource:@"google" ofType:@"p12" inDirectory:[[NSBundle mainBundle] bundlePath]]];
OSStatus result = SecPKCS12Import((CFDataRef)certData, (CFDictionaryRef)options, &items);
assert(result == errSecSuccess);
CFIndex count = CFArrayGetCount(items);
NSLog(@"Certificates found: %ld",count);
```

The console result output is 'Certificates found: 0'. The *certData* variable gets filled with the correct amount of bytes, and if I change the provided password, the results changes to *errSecAuthFailed*.

Do you have any idea what the problem might be?

Comment: In my case did work. One thing to notice passphrases not equal. "google" != "pass:google".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd say that's a bug, see related question [SSL Identity Certificate to run an HTTPS Server on iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9874932/ssl-identity-certificate-to-run-an-https-server-on-ios) and bug [SecPKCS12Import returns empty array when certificate expires after Jan 1st 10000](https://openradar.appspot.com/14553560).

As you only want a certificate, without the private key, I'd import the certificate from a DER format file.

```
$ openssl x509 -in google.pem -out google.der -outform DER
$ openssl x509 -in google.der -noout -text
```

Bundle DER certificate file and import it:

```
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"google" ofType:@"der"];
NSData *derData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:path];
SecCertificateRef cert = SecCertificateCreateWithData(NULL, (CFDataRef)derData);

// add cert to KeyChain or use it as you need

CFRelease(cert);
```