# SecPKCS12Import when p12 requries an empty passphrase

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, macos, security

I have a private key in p12 which has empty passphrase set.
Now when I'm trying to import this private key using `SecPKCS12Import` on OS X or iOS, I've got an error (equivalent on Windows works).

```
- (NSError *)setClientIdentityCertificateFromPKCS12Data: (NSData *)PKCS12Data withPassword: (NSString *)password
{
    OSStatus securityError = errSecSuccess;

    const void *keys[] =   { kSecImportExportPassphrase };
    const void *values[] = { (__bridge CFStringRef)password };
    CFDictionaryRef optionsDictionary = NULL;

    optionsDictionary = CFDictionaryCreate(
                                           NULL, keys,
                                           values, (password?1:0),
                                           NULL, NULL);
    CFArrayRef items = NULL;

    securityError = SecPKCS12Import((__bridge CFDataRef)PKCS12Data,
                                    optionsDictionary,
                                    &items);
```

I've tried different combinations when password is empty:

- `optionsDictionary = NULL`
- `optionsDictionary` with no values
- `optionsDictionary` with `@""` value for key `kSecImportExportPassphrase`

It always ends with `securityError` not equal to `errSecSuccess`. Respectively:

- `securityError=-25260` "Passphrase is required for import/export."
- `securityError=-25260` "Passphrase is required for import/export."
- `securityError=-25264` "MAC verification failed during PKCS12 import (wrong password?)"

Now I'm Ok that it doesn't work. I understudy that `p12` without a password is a security threat, but If this is the reason why it doesn't work I need some documentation which states that.
I've tried to Google that without luck so far.

I've also tried to import this file to OS X Keychain application with same result (invalid password), so this must be problem with `SecPKCS12Import`.

Or maybe there is a way to overcome this problem?

Answer (score 2):

I believe this is a defect with the Cocoa SDK, see [`rdar://22909471`](http://www.openradar.me/22909471).

Unfortunately, this radar has been closed as a dupe of an existing radar.  I would file an additional bug report with Apple to elevate this issue.  I can think of two alternatives:

1. Add a password your p12 blob.
2. Convert the certificate to DER encoding.  [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18365182/2415822) may help.

Answer (score 2):

This seems to be fixed by now, I've tested it on iOS 10. I can use an empty string as the password for my p12. However it seems like the `kSecImportExportPassphrase` is still required.